# Why I get two char in arr_str[i]?

Tags: android, split

First, I add data to Real Time DB of firebase

```
for(int i =0;i<16;i++)
    {
        myRef = database.getReference("Grid").child("Room1").child("grid"+i);
        mystring = Arrays.toString(GameEngine.my_grid[i]); 
     // my_grid is matrix 2D I declared  " int[][] my_grid "
        myRef.setValue(mystring);
    }
```

Second, I read data from DB

```
for (int i =0 ; i<16 ; i++) {
     String value = dataSnapshot.child("grid1").getValue(String.class);
     Log.d("GetData", "Value is: " + value);
     final String[] string_arrays = value.split(",");
         for(int j=0;j<16;j++) {
            Log.d("GetData", "String array "+j+" is: " +string_arrays[j]);
            }
}
```

And this is result

```
D/GetData: Value is: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
D/GetData: String array 0 is: [1
D/GetData: String array 1 is:  1
...
D/GetData: String array 15 is:  1]
```

I think I print only one char in string

---

But now I know how to explain this problem

Because I declare variable like this

```
String[] string_arrays ;
```

It's like

```
string_arrays[0]     // this type is String 
string_arrays[1]
.
.
.
string_arrays[n]
```

So when I use this function

```
String[] string_arrays = value.split(","); // return array of string 
   // 1st string : "[1"
   // 2nd string : "1"
   // ...
   // last string : "1]"
Log.d("GetData", "String array "+j+" is: " +string_arrays[j]);
```

---

Result :

Last, I think the value that return from split() is Array of char but it's Array of string, So When I print the value that return from split() it can show more than one char.

Comment: use  text.replace("["","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible options. Firstly, if you are sure that the text will only be surrounded by square brackets:

```
final String[] array = value.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
```

Or secondly, assuming that you'll always want to ignore the first and final characters

```
final String[] array = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1).split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend many time with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I am pretty sure the string would have `[` and `]`. This is how you can remove it. Its a simple replacement on the corrupt values.

```
value = value.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(value.split("\\s*,\\s*")); // This would consider useless white spaces before and after comma too.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work.